# Defining a bijective function that inputs and outputs a function

Tags: functions

Given $f:A \to B$ and $g: C \to D$ bijective.

I want to define a bijective function $F: C^A \to D^B$ where $C^A= \{h| h: A \to C\}$.

**My attempt:** We know the function $F$ takes in a function that goes from $A \to C$.

So I tried defining it by $F(\phi)=g(\phi(f^{-1}(t)))$ and this is indeed a function that goes from $B \to D$.

Then I tried to show that it's injective & surjective.

Because I don't know anything about $\phi$ in particular I do not know whether if it is injective or surjective I am doubting my approach. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: $\phi$ will often be neither injective or surjective but you don't care. It's $F$ you want to show is bijective. Try to write down its inverse - just think of how you would have tackled the problem if you were told the inverses of $f$ and $g$ instead of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Even if I were told the inverse of $f$ and $g$ I believe that it does not help me or I can't see it. Like the sets $A,B,C,D$ are 4 separate sets not related to each other in any way. The inverses would just go $B \to A$ and $D \to C$ and $\phi$ can't be replaced by any of the inverses because $\phi$ goes from $A$ to $C$ and there is no functions that takes it from $A$ to $C$ at least from the given functions... I would appreciate a little more hint! Thanks. I do not see a way to compose a function that takes it from $A$ to $C$..

Comment: Anyone...? It seems the guy above doesn't know either.

Comment: Ethan Bolker did know, and told you, but you didn't understand him. You don't need to know anything about $\phi$ other than it is a function from $A \to C$. It is $F$ itself you need to prove is bijective, not $\phi$ or $F(\phi)$. Having defined $F : C^A \to D^B$, try now defining $G: D^B \to C^A$ in the same manner. How are $F$ and $G$ related?

Comment: Thank you. Defining $G$ in the same manner as in the way I did it or in some other way? And if you are referring to the same manner as in "my way" then I have done so. But still does not ring a bell on how I can show that $F$ is bijective. $F$ and $G$ are related such that when you compose $F$ with $G$ or vice versa you'll end up with the identity function is that what you are referring to?

Comment: So it's not $F(\phi)$ that I'm trying to show it's bijective... $F$ itself I'm only familiar with proving bijective by showing that its injective and surjective. And showing that a function is injective or surjective stricly relies using the parameter that $F$ that takes in. Like for example, given $y \in D$ we know because $g$ is into there exists a $c\in C$ such that $g(c)=d$... and then the trouble appears here not knowing anything about $\phi$. But this is the wrong approach as you said. But this is the only approach I am aware of showing a function is surjective or injective.